# Storing Count value from query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jdbc

How do I store the returned count value into a variable, so I can then set a attribute with it? This is  my method so far:

```
public List<Sighting> total() {

     return jdbc.query("select pest_name, count(pest_name) from sighting group by pest_name", new RowMapper<Sighting>() {
         public Sighting mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Sighting sighting = new Sighting();
                sighting.setCount(????); // I need to pass a variable to setCount()
                sighting.setPest_name(rs.getString("pest_name"));
                return sighting;
            }      
       });
}
```

That count value in a query..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either specify a name for the count, e.g.

```
return jdbc.query("select pest_name, count(pest_name) as pest_count from sighting group by pest_name", new RowMapper<Sighting>() {
         public Sighting mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Sighting sighting = new Sighting();
                sighting.setCount(rs.getInt("pest_count"));
                sighting.setPest_name(rs.getString("pest_name"));
                return sighting;
            }      
       });
```

... or just fetch it by column number:

```
return jdbc.query("select pest_name, count(pest_name) from sighting group by pest_name", new RowMapper<Sighting>() {
         public Sighting mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Sighting sighting = new Sighting();
                sighting.setCount(rs.getInt(2));
                sighting.setPest_name(rs.getString("pest_name"));
                return sighting;
            }      
       });
```

You may need to use `getLong` instead of `getInt`.

Comment: Thank you immensely. Both solutions were tested and worked correctly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try with :

```
Select pest_name, count(pest_name)  as totalCount
```

and in the resultset try with

```
long count = rs.getLong("totalCount")
```

Answer (score 0):

Name your count. Change

```
"select pest_name, count(pest_name) from sighting group by pest_name"
```

to

```
"select pest_name, count(pest_name) as pest_count from sighting group by pest_name"
```